Reproducing table titles in Kitted PDFs - tables built using gtsummary package in R
I am building tables using R's gtsummary package - tlb_cross, tbl_regression, tbl_summary - and I am unable to render table titles when Knitting to PDF, although I am able to render these titles when Knitting to HTML.
Here is some sample code:

output:
pdf_document: default
html_document: default
#Create dataset

ds<-data.frame(
  Exposure=sample(c(0,1), 500, replace = T),
  Outcome=sample(c(1,0), 500, replace = T)
)

#Create table
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)

ds %>% tbl_summary(label = list(Exposure="Treatment", 
                                 Outcome="Disease")) %>%
  modify_caption("**Table 1. Sample Characteristics**") %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  as_gt %>%
  gt::tab_source_note(gt::md("*Note:* This is a test table to troubleshoot the absence of a title when Kniting PDF documents."))

ds %>% tbl_cross(row=Outcome, col=Exposure, percent="cell",
  label=list(Exposure="Treatment", Outcome="Disease"), margin=c(NULL)) %>%
  add_p() %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  modify_caption("<div style='text-align: left; font-weight: bold; color: black'> Table 2. Crosstabulation")

Example of PDF output
Example of HTML output
The HTML output renders the table titles how I would like to see them in the PDF. Any suggestions on how to get the titles to display in the PDF as they display in the HTML?
